# IPTables cannot resolve dns

Tags: iptables, debian-squeeze, resolve

I'm running Debian 6 32Bit
I finally just setup my iptables, but I cannot seem to 
connect to any external server from my box

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -j ACCEPT --dports 80,22,53,47240,3306
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m multiport -j ACCEPT --dports 80,22,53,47240,3306
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

Also, is it necessary for me to allow 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

to the beginning to allow incoming answer packages.

Comment: im getting an error with that  unknown "m"

Comment: I have edited my answer because the dash was missing before the m.

Comment: thankyou, can you shed some light on why this needs to be added?

Comment: Because if you connect to an outer box it's OK that your packages can reach that box but if you filter out responses than you can't communicate. This rule says that all traffic for established connections and also related packages can get in.